# Android WebView + loadUrl with javascript + onPageFinished = lag

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have WebView which loads some page, when it's finished I apply some javascript magic to mess up with DOM. Everything is fine, page loads and `onPageFinished` I just call `wv.loadUrl(javascript);`

But I don't want to see loading process, and how javascript is working, I just need result, so I made my view invisible with `wv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` from the start, and make it visible again when everything is done. This is where problem occurs.

This piece of code should make view visible after javascript is finished, but `wv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` fires before javascript. So for a moment I see page and how it is being changed by javascript. This is just ugly.

```
  public void onPageFinished (WebView view, String url) {
         wv.loadUrl(javascript);
         view.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
         wv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
```

I got that loadUrl works asynchronously, so I tried to make another WebViewClient with just "make first view visible" method inside `onPageFinished`, and use it to call JS. But it just keeps crashing with NPE error.

```
wv2.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished (WebView view, String url) {
     wv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
});
```

For now I just added delay after javascript (`SystemClock.sleep(5000)`), but this is like.. yeah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I figured it out. We can have callback from the end of javascript that will fire "show view" - like [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) or [here](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/Samples/WebViewDemo/src/com/google/android/webviewdemo/WebViewDemo.java) (with handler, because I wanted to update ui).
But it wont change anything, the problem seems to be in rendering speed. It's just slow. So for now I'll just stick with 1 second delay after firing JS.

Comment: I think we have a solution for this bug: http://android-know-how-to.blogspot.co.il/2013/08/android-webview-javascript-onpagefinish.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're going to get an easy solution to this. All that Android can detect (like most browsers) is when the page is fully loaded, which means, all of it is downloaded. Javascript waits for it to be downloaded also, and THEN starts running. It's just the way it works. The only solution I can think of might just be in JQuery. I don't know much about it but there's usually solutions to things like this in it.

Comment: It's not a problem of detecting whether page is loaded or not. Problem is why other methods firing before javascript is finished?

Comment: Because technically speaking, and according to your browser, the page is finished loading. Javascript running, and the page rendering are two completely separate things. The Javascript only runs when the page is fully downloaded, and you are only able to detect when the page is fully downloaded. I'm not an expert on Javascript or JQuery, but I do think that you will find your solution with a JQuery question, if there is one.