# How do I make JavaScript-Java communication sync in Android WebView?

Tags: java, javascript, android, webkit

I've got WebView, JS code inside it. Also I have interface to allow Java method invocation from WebView to Java code. **I need to pass data from JS to Java.** To do so:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:getData()");

//Obtain Java object here
```

In JavaScript:

```
function gataData () {
    //serialize data to JSON, pass it as 'native' function param
    JSInterface.setLocationsData(data);// This calls a Java function setLocationsData(String param)
}
```

In JavaScript interface(Java code):

```
 void setLocationsData(String param){
    //parse JSON here, create Java Object
 }
```

The problem is: I've got a delay between calling script in WebView after webView.loadUrl() and moment when data is returned to my Java code. Java code doesn't wait for JS to finish it's business. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only (hacky) solution that I've come across is using a [one second delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820237/android-webview-loadurl-with-javascript-onpagefinished-lag) after calling  the loadUrl. You may use the [addJavaSriptInterface()](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/trunk/Samples/WebViewDemo/src/com/google/android/webviewdemo/WebViewDemo.java) to do so.

or if the JS processing takes too long you have to use callbacks

```
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="callYourCallbackFunctionHere('Hello Android!')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function callYourCallbackFunctionHere(toast) {
        Android.callAndroidCallback(toast);
    }
</script>
```

---

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    public void callAndroidCallback(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I already have JSInterface, so I need to make a callback in it and to proceed in program only when that callback is called. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: how powerful is this solution? can we do full java <-> javascript communication using those methods or are there some important limitations? thanks!